# How to decode PDF created with Quartz PDFContext?

Tags: macos, security, pdf, core-graphics, decode

I recieved very strange PDF-contract with sender's possibility of remote real time conditions and payment adress changing against me, to scam me.

One of the PDF layers with text is readable but there are still hidden parts of the text. 
The code inside PDF is encrypted. It created with Quartz PDFContext (macOS Version 10.15.3)

How could we decode that PDF and read that code inside PDF to proof the scam against me?

Thanx in advance

Comment: What do you imagine you'd be able to do with the content once you got it?  It's likely machine-generated spam, there's no identifiable person to send the cops after.  I hate saying "just delete it", but it's likely not worth your time.

Comment: will be the next step. for first step need to look inside the code of pdf

Comment: and that was not spam. we had 3 months negotiations and conditions discussing before I recieved pdf contract from that investor-scammer

Comment: For decryption of standard pdf encryption use tools like qpdf.

Comment: Brother thank you a lot!